# Max resolution available is 1024x768, while I should expect 1280x1024

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, resolution

The max resolution what I can choose is 1024x768. What shall I do to have 1280x1024 (max resolution of my monitor) option too?

My configuration:

- a Siemens brand PC
- Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot
- Samsung SyncMater 913n TFT monitor via analog (D-Sub) connection
- Graphics card is reported to be (`lspci`):

  ```
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated 
          Graphics Controller [8086:2572] (rev 02)
  ```

  and `lshw`:

  ```
  *-display
      description: VGA compatible controller
      product: 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 2
      bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
      version: 02
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
      configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
      resources: irq:16 memory:f0000000-f7ffffff memory:e0000000-e007ffff ioport:1000(size=8)
  ```

Comment: Any reason for using Ubuntu 11.10 still? Two new stable releases have followed this already. Also, provide more information: (`lspci -nn | grep -iE "(vga|graphics)"`, `sudo lshw -C display`, monitor brand/model, connection type (D-Sub/DVI/...), what application are you using to adjust the resolution?

Comment: You can add resolutions with `xrandr`. There are several topics on AU about `xrandr`. Example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/138408/how-to-add-display-resolution-fo-an-lcd-in-ubuntu-12-04-xrandr-problem but you need a bit of information about your card. @gertvdijk 's comment probably will get you those ;)

Comment: @gertvdijk:  The outputs are bellow. I use Samsung SyncMater 913n TFT monitor via analog (D-Sub) connection.                  user1@user1-SCENIC-E:~$ lspci -nn | grep -iE "(vga|graphics)"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2572] (rev 02)

Comment: @gertvdijk the second results:                            user1@user1-SCENIC-E:~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 82865G Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f0000000-f7ffffff memory:e0000000-e007ffff ioport:1000(size=8)

Comment: @ZoltánO. Thanks, but **edit** your question next time, rather than posting output in an unformatted way in comments. I've done this for you this time. Have you tried to boot from a live CD with Ubuntu 12.04.1/12.10 and see if your problem is solved in a more recent version?

Comment: @gertvdijk Thanks for your help. I tried Ubuntu 12.04.1 not only with live CD but I installed it too. There I have the same problem and there was no sound either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be running into a specific combination of hardware bug. It is already reported as [LP Bug #783165](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/783165) and I think it's caused by something odd in the EDID of your display that confuses the `i915` driver. Make sure you mark yourself as affected in that bug report, subscribe to updates if you like and feel free to post a working workaround in the bug report. This could be useful for anyone else running into the same and hitting to the bug report rather than the Q&A here.

#### Workaround

There's [this workaround](http://www.chrisnewland.com/samsung-syncmaster-913n-1280x1024-resolution-in-debian-and-ubuntu-89) I spotted on `chrisnewland.com`:

> Use the `xrandr` command to get the detected modes
>
> ```
> chriswhocodes@debian:~$ xrandr  Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current
> 1024 x 768, maximum 4096 x 4096  VGA-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal
> left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm    1360x768       59.8   
> 1024x768       60.0*    800x600        60.3     56.2      848x480     
> 60.0      640x480        59.9     59.9
> ```
>
> Note the name of the screen, here it is VGA-0 but yours may differ
>
> Use the `cvt` command to get a `Modeline` string for the resolution you want (1280x1024)
>
> ```
> chriswhocodes@debian:~$ cvt 1280 1024 
> # 1280x1024 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.31M4) hsync: 63.67 kHz; pclk: 109.00 MHz  Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027
> 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
> ```
>
> Now copy everything after the word Modeline into the xrandr --newmode command
>
> ```
> chriswhocodes@debian:~$ xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00 
> 1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
> ```
>
> Now add the mode to your screen
>
> ```
> chriswhocodes@debian:~$ xrandr --addmode VGA-0 1280x1024_60.00
> ```
>
> Now change to the new resolution
>
> ```
> chriswhocodes@debian:~$ xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode 1280x1024_60.00
> ```
>
> You should now be running at 1280x1024 but you need the next step to make it permanent

From here the posted workaround seems to be out of date. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/187430/88802) on how to make it permanent.

Comment: Now its fine up to have resolution. But I can not save it. There is no gdm directory under my /etc. I made a grep with MC and it did not find anywhere files "Default" and after that did not find file which contains OLD_IFS=$IFS strings.

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right about GDM not available. This seems changed in recent Ubuntu releases and using LightDM. Could anyone elaborate on changing this for Ubuntu 11.10+? I'm running KDM/Kubuntu here and totally not an expert on this particular piece of configuration.

Comment: I can find the missing last part [on this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138408/how-to-add-display-resolution-fo-an-lcd-in-ubuntu-12-04-xrandr-problem). After creating my “/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf” file I've got 1280*1024 resolution. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @ZoltánO. Great to hear it helped you work around this bug. I've incorporated the last piece from the link you posted in my answer. Consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer if you think it was helpful.