# Lenovo T430s, Ubuntu 13.04, unknown monitor

Tags: display

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a Lenovo T430s. I connected an external monitor via the VGA port (Samsung SyncMaster 2443). When I go to the Display settings, the monitor appears as "unknown", and the maximum resolution is 1024 x 768.

(The maximum resolution is 1920 x 1200 on Windows 7.)

I tried turning Optimus mode on/off, I tried installing Bumblebee, and I tried installing the latest Intel drivers through intel-linux-graphics-installer, to no avail. How can I get Ubuntu to recognize the monitor and/or enable a higher resolution?

Answer (score 0):

This guide (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution) can lead you out of desperation and help you understand the problem, this ([How to add display resolution for an LCD in Ubuntu 12.04? xrandr problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138408/how-to-add-display-resolution-fo-an-lcd-in-ubuntu-12-04-xrandr-problem)) would be the quick solution.

There was also a bug on Nvidia cards, and it looks like it is still active. please confirm what is your graphics card type.