# Display Resolution on 10.04/12.04/13.04

Tags: display

Is there a 'FIX' to the Display > Resolution problem on ubuntu 10.04/12.04/13.04 on some machines.  My dELL-Vostro 200 screen needs a resolution of 1280x1024, with any ubuntu installation I have tried it's not there on 12.04 there is only 1024x768 and 800x600 on offer. On the 10.04 there was an 1170aprox by whatever/something.
The resolution is perfect on Virtual... but then there are other problems. I deleted it. Please Help!

Comment: you can add resolutions with `xrandr` http://askubuntu.com/questions/138408/how-to-add-display-resolution-fo-an-lcd-in-ubuntu-12-04-xrandr-problem?rq=1

Comment: Or depeneing on your skill set you could try arandr, a graphical front end for xrandr.