# Xubuntu 14.04 resolution low

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, resolution, screen

I installed Xubuntu 14.04 amd64 on the computer at the computer repair shop where I work, but the screen resolution is way low, like 1024 x 768 (that wouldn't be low for a laptop or anything, but for a large desktop screen it is) I went to the display settings, but the resolution wouldn't go higher than that.

When I installed Xubuntu 14.04 i386 at my computer at home, I didn't have any problems with the resolution. Any help?

**Update:** I ran `lspci | grep VGA`
and got:

```
00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2)
```

Comment: identify your hardware (video card) on the computer running in low resolution.

Comment: If you will provide AMD processor Model and Graphics card info to clarify your question, it will give you a better chance of getting the help you need.  You my need to download microcode or a linux driver for the graphics card, but specifics will be needed.

Comment: Perhaps you should install the "Additional Driver" (`software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4`) for your graphics. Or this could help [How to add display resolution fo an LCD in Ubuntu 12.04? xrandr problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138408/how-to-add-display-resolution-fo-an-lcd-in-ubuntu-12-04-xrandr-problem) || [How to set the monitor to its native resolution which is not listed in the resolutions list?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol/19956)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after installing proprietary drivers for my ATI Mobility Radeon 4570 HD. It was the same with *fglrx*, *fglrx-updates*, *fglrx-amdcce* and *fglrx-amdcce-updates*. Removing all of them, resultion came back as before. It should be noted that they are in conflict, so only one package at time should be installed. I tried to do so, but the problem persisted. Remove all of them turned into the best solution for me. Hope this could help.