# 2560 x 1080 Screen Resolution on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: resolution, monitor

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a mac mini and bought a 2560 x 1080 ultrawide LG monitor for it. Problem is that it doesn't display the proper resolution, the maximum being 1920 x 1080 under ubuntu settings.

Any suggestions on what I should do?

*Please give clear instructions as am not an Ubuntu expert.*

Comment: What graphics card do you have?

Comment: How do I check this?

Comment: Umm `lspci | grep VGA` in the terminal. For example mine says `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation`, so I have a nvidia Graphics card.

Comment: I just checked under settings, not terminal. Apparently it's a "Gallium 0.4 on NVAC".

Comment: Terminal says this: 02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C79 [GeForce 9400] (rev b1)

Comment: Okay, good. Run `nvidia-settings` and then select `X Server Display  Configuration`. Then you might be able to adjust it (but I also can only go up to 1920x1080). I think that may be the max on ubuntu.

Comment: Is there some other possible command? Because "X Server Display Configuration" didn't work for me.

Comment: This is what happens when I type in nvidia-settings: ** (nvidia-settings:3898): WARNING **: PRIME: Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/prime-supported" (No such file or directory)
** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no

Comment: Does a window not open?

Comment: Yes, it does... But it seems to not have the options you mentioned.

Comment: Is there a way I can show you a screenshot of my computer?

Comment: So on the left is a list of things, click the second one? Then you see a diagram of your screen(s). Click the screen and then there is a drop down next to resolution. Click that, and see if you can select the resolution you want. If not , I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Sure, press Printscreen and then upload it to http://imgur.com

Comment: I'll have to do it later, though, cuz I've gotta go. Thank you so much for your help so far...

Comment: Is there a way to send private messages on this? I could send you my whatsapp number, and take a picture with my phone. that would be a lot quicker.

Comment: No, sorry. This is the closest thing to instant messaging. Imgur is quick.

Comment: http://imgur.com/miFbXcq

Comment: I don't know then... I'm afraid, from research I've been doing that 1920x1080 is the max on ubuntu.

Comment: I read somewhere that ubuntu 13 could do it... Maybe it's a matter of time before they update? Anyway, thanks for your help, Tim.

Comment: Maybe...? That's okay, sorry I didn't give more help...

Comment: Did you by any chance find out in your research if my graphics card is capable of 2560x1080?

Comment: Hmm don't know sorry...

Comment: DVI/HDMI: 2560x1600 VGA: 2048x1536

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks. I guess I'll just wait for an update.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add display resolution fo an LCD in Ubuntu 12.04? xrandr problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/138408/how-to-add-display-resolution-fo-an-lcd-in-ubuntu-12-04-xrandr-problem)

Answer (score 3):

2560x1080 for a 29" ultra wide monitor is not supported on Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10.

Bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xrandr/+bug/1357804

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see resolution option in nvdia-settings, is because you probably didn't install the nvidia driver. You should install the nvidia driver of your corresponding gpu

with this command : `$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

or you can go to follow this link: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us .

After doing this reboot,  and type in terminal: `$ lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12`

You should see :    "Kernel driver in use: nvidia"

instead of ubuntu default  driver "noveau".

After doing this type in terminal: `$ gksudo nvidia-setting`
and  change settings to desired resolution in " X server Display Configuration"

Answer (score 0):

The typical way would be to solve this with a custom modeline that defines how the graphics driver should communicate with the panel.

[How to add display resolution for an LCD in Ubuntu 12.04? xrandr problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/138408/40581)

Contrary to suggestions for installing proprietary drivers, this would probably work best with the open source drivers.

Edit: It's probably worth to mention that the graphics port and the monitor cable also have to support the mode the screen requires to run the optimal resolution and refresh rate. Bad VGA/DVI/HDMI/DP cables and unsupported HDMI/DP modes or non Dual Link DVI ports can be an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the same OS. Everything worked fine after I've updated to the latest Nvidia proprietary drivers. I see that you are also using a Nivida graphic card.

Step by step:

1. Check if you are using an HDMI or Display Port cable
2. Install the latest [proprietary drivers from Nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers).
3. Execute the just installed Nvidia setting app and select the desired setting.

Answer (score 0):

The newer Linux kernel most likely supports your hardware, 14.04 is running a rather ancient one. Consider upgrading to the newest kernel 4.8.2 by downloading the necessary .deb files from the Ubuntu mainline kernel repository at http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.2/

Comment: maybe first ask what kernel is currently used.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only switching to Nouveau drivers helped.

1. Install nouveau package, relevant to your distribution.
2. Disable blacklisting from "/usr/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf".
3. Add noveau drivers to xorg configuration.

Reference: [Missing 2560x1080 from Linux Nvidia Control Panel](https://browse-tutorials.com/tutorial/missing-2560x1080-linux-nvidia-control-panel)

Comment: Please provide the essential part of the solution. Share the link only as reference and more detail