# Why can't I see 16:9 aspect ratios?

Tags: display, vga

[image: This what my display settings look like with the TV]

So for a while I have had an old EMA 15" monitor hooked up to my Ubuntu   machine running Ubuntu 15.04. The Monitor runs  1024x768 (4:3). At this point all is fine. But I hooked my computer to my Sansui HDTV and it will not let me have a 16:9 ratio so it is in letter box. How do I fix this?

NOTE: I am using a VGA cable between the TV and COMPUTER. Also I am used to Ubuntu and the terminal so please HELP!!!

```
$ sudo xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Can you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/712564/edit) your post and past the results of `sudo xrandr -q`

Comment: With the TV or MOnitor connected?

Comment: Yes with the T.V/Monitor connected

Comment: Im sorry I meant wihich one tv OR monitor.

Comment: With the TV hooked up the one you are trying to get 16:9

Comment: OK i added the code into the post

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Type this into your terminal: `sudo cvt 1366 768`. It will output something similar to:

```
# 1366x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1366x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

Yours may be different than what I have, so copy everything after "Modeline" from your terminal.

Now paste in what you copied into this command, e.g.
`sudo xrandr --newmode "1366x768_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync`

The final step is to add the new resolution to the VGA1: `sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 1366x768_60.00`

That should give you the resolution you want for the TV.

To keep the settings after restart use the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/187430/238718) with your settings and you won't have to redo it.

Comment: this worked BUT my tv is weird it only accepts 1080 from some sources so could you change the code for 720

Comment: @dubCraftNation I have updated the answer for you to 720p 16:9

Comment: for some reson 720p is too small to fill whole screen but 1080 is not supported any suggestions?

Comment: What is your model of  Sansui HDTV?

Comment: Sansui sled2900

Comment: Monitor Display modes
Mode Resolution Refresh rate
VGA 640x480 60/ 72/ 75 Hz
VGA 720x400 70Hz
SVGA 800x600 56/ 60/ 72/ 75 Hz
XGA 1024x768 60/ 70/ 75 Hz
WXGA 1280x768 60Hz
WXGA 1280x720 60Hz
WXGA 1360x768 60Hz

Comment: Which do you think will work for me?

Comment: Go with 1360x768

Comment: I have updated the answer to the resolution of 1360x768

Comment: btw every time i restart my pc the added resolution option goes away in settings

Comment: @dubCraftNation I added a answer to a similar question for the answer to the restart problem

Comment: 768 is still small, i can use the FULL format tv setting and it streches up to my screen size but the picture quality suffers greatly by doing this... any suggestion?

Comment: 768 is still small, i can use the FULL format tv setting and it streches up to my screen size but the picture quality suffers greatly by doing this... any suggestion?

Comment: The specs of the tv are `Analog Tuner  NTSC
Video Signal Standard  HDTV
Maximum Resolution  1366 x 768
Dynamic Contrast Ratio  1,000,000:1
Comb Filter  3D Y/C
Scan Format  720p `    So you should be able to use 1366x768 Did you ajust for somthing else befor using it as a monitor

Comment: so 1366x768?   If that is the max then it should fill the screen right?

Comment: It *should* yes

Comment: what do you mean did i ajust for something else

Comment: I meant  *adjust*  Say for a dvd player or blue ray player did you use the fill full screen setting or zoom with the aspect ratio button most LCD TV's  have now a days

Comment: can you please change you answer to 1366

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Neither `cvt` nor `xrandr` require root (sudo).

Answer (score 3):

I added a 1504x846 res (16:9) for my Dell XPS since the highest it had was "1366x768".

```
cvt 1504 846 60
xrandr --newmode "1504x846" 104.50  1504 1592 1744 1984  846 849 854 878 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode LVDS-1 "1504x846"
```

I then went to the "Menu -> Display" panel and picked it.  profit!

note, run `xrandr| grep primary` to get your correct display name.  Mine was "LVDS-1".

Comment: I am getting this error -  Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to manually set your display resolution:

The settings are under `Settings --> Displays`.  You need to set your resolution for that monitor to `1920x1080`.  See [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SQ_N-mQCmIc).

Comment: It does not show that resolution I aded a link with picture.

Comment: Hmmm, what's the output of `ls /etc/X11`?

Comment: There should be a config file in there that has a list of monitor modes.

Comment: 'code'$ ls /etc/X
ls: cannot access /etc/X: No such file or directory

Comment: See edit to comment

Comment: It should be `/etc/X11` sorry for typo

Comment: ls /etc/X11
app-defaults             fonts    xkb       Xresources  Xsession.options
cursors                  rgb.txt  Xreset    Xsession    xsm
default-display-manager  xinit    Xreset.d  Xsession.d  Xwrapper.config

Comment: Now do this: `cd /etc/X11/ ; grep -R 1024x768 *`