# Ubuntu doesn't recognize my widescreen display

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 on my desktop pc but it doesn't recognize my display/monitor, it literally says "unknown display" and it stays in a 4:3 resolution and the only options available are other 4:3 resolutions except for one 16:9 resolution that doesn't really work for some reason.
I've already installed the proprietary driver for my graphics card and restarted my pc several times.
and hitting "detect displays" does literally nothing.

what's weird is that when I tried out Ubuntu from a memory stick without installing to check if everything was ok, it worked perfectly fine and it recognized my monitor.

my graphics card is a GeForce 9400gt and my monitor I don't really know but it says "Samsung SyncMaster 2033" on it, I'm assuming that's the brand and model but not sure.

I've seen a lot of people with the same problem when googling, but none of their answers worked for me.

Comment: I only chime in here because I dealt with the same problem on 16.04...Have you selected a proprietary driver for your nVidia GPU? If you go into "Software & Updates" and look at the tab "Additional Drivers"... You should see a short list of available video drivers. One of those should be "nouveax". If you try that driver, on subsequent reboot, you will be using the same driver as the "Live Mode" used. If that gives you correct resolution, then you know that the proprietary driver is the problem. I was lucky that the system offered a few proprietary choices. One of which worked perfectly for me

Comment: yeah, I've tried that, on "Software & Updates" and then "Aditional Drivers" there's 3 drivers for my GPU, I've tried all of them, including the one that says "Nouveau", 2 of them are proprietary drivers, no luck.

Comment: can you post the output of `xrandr` ?

Comment: @bistoco it won't let me, says comment too long.

Comment: use [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to share the content

Comment: @bistoco [link](https://pastebin.com/R5QB8nPA)

Comment: [This is a solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/712581/260379) for 16:9 on 720p, follow the instructions but change `VGA1` to `DVI-I-0` as your `xrandr` shows.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the resolution configuration file to force it to the right size, or make sure that you have the correct drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing official Nvidia GPU drivers: http://www.geforce.com/drivers