# 16:9 aspect ratios are missing and if added manually picture is pixelated

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display, display-resolution

I have installed LXLE distro installed on an old PC with Nvidia GeForce FX 5700 graphics card and Samsung SyncMaster 2333 HD display. Both the graphics card and the display support full HD, yet all 16:9 resolutions are missing from settings.

I tried adding it manually as described in [why-cant-i-see-169-aspect-ratios](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712564/why-cant-i-see-169-aspect-ratios) and while it seems to give me the higher resolution, the picture is horribly pixelated.

Below are the commands I ran:

```
> sudo xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 4096 x 4096
DVI-I-1 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 320mm
   1680x1050     59.88* 
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
TV-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> sudo cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
> sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
> sudo xrandr --addmode DVI-I-2 1920x1080_60.00
```

Before installing LXLE I have also tried Debian 9 and run into the same issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I forgot - I installed LXLE 18.04.3 to be specific.

Comment: GeForce FX 5700 is from 2003. It is 17 years old, and I doubt it can support full HD, especially, not without a proper Nvidia driver. You might want to try a saner 16:9 resolution like 1366x768, or use an available one.